# Ubuntu Installation Help? - "The system is running low-graphics mode"

Tags: installation

I have a PowerMac G5 With a powerpc dual and I am trying to install ubuntu 13, I have a nvidia GeForce 6600LE. Everytime I try to install ubuntu it passes the dots and then comes up with this error.

Answer (score 1):

Please execute the commands below and reboot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

I think this is because it's using a fail safe and going to the default graphics config...

or use this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee